# For programing C#, is recommended that I know C and C++, or it just gets in the way?

Tags: c#, c++, c

For me to learn C++ I have to know C?
For me to learn C# I have to know C++ and C?

Comment: If you already know these languages it's a plus but it doesn't mean you NEED to know them.

Comment: Not really the place to ask such a question as you're unlikely to get a factual answer.

Comment: It's a completely different language. I wouldn't recommend learning any of the three before any other, if the goal is to learn only one of them.

Comment: To be fair its more similar to Java but you can have a look at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/144075/learn-c-before-at-the-same-time-as-c and also http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/74165/is-learning-c-easy-when-you-already-know-c

Comment: For me, C++ is an obstacle for mastering C#, because there are similar concepts, which turn out slightly differently. Same as Java and C++

Comment: Personally, I think that it is unnecessary to know these languages: C# is a different language, its only borrows some syntax concepts from C/C++. Whole standard library is different. Moreover, personally I think that knowing C before you learn C++ (a little off-topic) can do more **harm** than not knowing it - many good practices in C are considered bad in C++. I suppose that this is still true for C#.

Comment: The next time I see something tagged both [tag:c++] ***and*** [tag:c] , I'm going to cast a close vote without reading.

Comment: @RomanSaveljev: And the opposite is true as well: Java and C# can be obstacles to learning C++, like PHP can be an obstacle to Python, and everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don't need to learn any of these languages before another, you may find c# easier to learn if you cant already program, although some people argue that you should learn c or c++ first as it will force you to manage memory yourself.

for c and c++:

http://www.durofy.com/programming/10-major-differences-between-c-and-c/

http://www.cplusplus.com/

for c#:

http://www.learnvisualstudio.net/series/visual_csharp_2010_express_edition_for_absolute_beginners/?gclid=CPPr_dem1bECFQRTfAodDCAAbQ

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436(v=vs.71).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/centrum-xna.aspx

Personally I would say go for c#, it is a nice language and easy to pick up (in my opinion), once you get the basics you could try making a game using xna game studio, it should keep you interested.

good luck :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to know C or C++ to learn C#. If you already know them, some of the C# syntax will be familiar, but learning C/C++ just to learn C# is definitely a waste of your time.

That said, C and C++ aren't bad languages to have a grip on, but if you're going to learn them, learn them for their own sake and not just for learning C#.